# Strange spinner nullpointerexception cause in Tablet

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I used three spinner in Fragment, all worked well. But when I run in Tablet error occurs.

**Logcat**

```
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:534)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:485)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:449)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1438)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
12-06 18:07:35.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20135):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At my time, I encountered like that cause setAdapter(null) didn't work in my testing tablet.
So, I changed my code.

Instead of `setAdapter(null)`, set new `ArrayList` in adapter.

I hope this will help !

Answer (score 0):

```
etUom = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.etUom);    
etUom.setAdapter(getDefaultAdapter());

ArrayAdapter<UomDetails> getDefaultAdapter() {
        List<UomDetails> result = new ArrayList<UomDetails>();
        ArrayAdapter<UomDetails> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<UomDetails>(
                getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, result);          adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        return adapter;
    }
```